# Serial Port Communication in Android

Tags: android, serial-port, android-hardware

I am trying to connect a TPMS(Tire Pressure Monitoring System) with my android application.TPMS is connected with my android device through Serial Port.
As i found that serial manager api are now hidden in android.
I just wanted to know alternate of serial api's or how can i use android serial port api.

Comment: its possible now... good luck...